# Are the Pop Fizz and Hot Dog Skylanders figurines only compatible with the Giants game?

Tags: skylanders, skylanders-giants

My son is asking for the Pop Fizz and Hot Dog figurines for Christmas, but he said he wants the ones for the original Skylanders game, not the Giants game.  Are these figurines only available for the Giants game?  That's all I seem to be finding.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those figures are for Skylanders 2 only.

Original Series:

- Spyro, Double Trouble, Wrecking Ball, Voodoo
- Bash, Dino-Rang, Terrafin, Prism Break
- Slam Bam, Zap, Wham-Shell, Gill Grunt
- Ignitor, Sunburn,Flameslinger, Eruptor
- Boomer, Drill Sergeant, Drobot, Trigger Happy
- Hex, Cynder, Chop Chop, Ghost Roaster
- Whirlwind, Warnado, Sonic Boom, Lightning Rod
- Camo, Stump Smash, Zook, Stealth Elf

Answer (score 1):

yes hot dog and pop fizz are only available for the giants game if he wants s2 zap then pick up the sqorpion striker pack if not just get the single hot dog and if he wants s2 whirlwind and s2 trigger happy get the triple pack with them in if not just get pop fizz single. but then if you get the pop fizz single don't worry because you can get s2 trigger happy and s2 whirlwind single aswell.